# Filtering elements selected by selenium through .find_elements_by_class_name using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I have a program that selects these yellow elements by their common class name.
[image]

I'm trying to further filter these selections by the column/row they're a part of, but I'm not sure how to filter my selenium selections further. This is a copy of the HTML for the elements I'm selecting.

[image]

Is it possible for me to first specify the XPATH of the date and then select the class elements within that date?

This is my current code to select these yellow elements.

```py
except NoSuchElementException:
        items = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("status3")
```

Comment: it's possible to to find_element on webdriver_element object. is there code of the page to take a look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say we need to get child elements of your date who has an xpath

```
date=driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath")
```

We could add //div[@class='status3'] in it's xpath as well to get all items or we do the following.

```
items=date.find_elements_by_class_name("status3")
```